# Exporting to CSV without formatted blank values

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, blank-line

I have a .xlsm with data tabs that's designed to auto populate some cells with data and then export those rows to a CSV file, however when I run my code it copies the entire active range including the cells that have been formatted to be blank and it exports them as commas, I've tried writing the code to delete the commas in the new CSV and I've tried writing the code to not copy over formatted blank values in the first place but nothing so far I've tried has worked.

So far I've spent a few months on this, and other people on the forums have the same issue but no one seems to have fixed it.

```
Sub Mcam_Order_Entry()
'
' Mcam_Order_Entry Macro
' GETS ORDER ENTRY FORM READY FOR TRUNEST
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'

Dim SB As Worksheet
Set SB = Worksheets("Sandbox")
Set n = SB.Cells(3, 2)
 

 Worksheets("PNM").Copy
 With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 .Copy
 .PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=False
 End With
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="I:\Group\DNC\MAGESTIC\Multicam\NEW MULTICAM DXFS\" & "Nest" & n & ".csv", _
 FileFormat:=xlCSVMac
 
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
 Range("F15").Select
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 ActiveWindow.Close
 Worksheets("Sandbox").Select
 Range("B3") = Range("B3") + 1
 Worksheets("PNM").Select
 Range("F2:F15").Select
 Selection.ClearContents
 Range("F2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Copy`/`PasteSpecial`, try `With ActiveSheet.UsedRange`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With`.

Comment: when I replace
"
 .Copy
 .PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=True, Transpose:=False
"

with
".value = .value"
 I get the same result, a file with a bunch of comas at the end or "bottom" because it's pulling the cells with formulas in them that are formulated blank.

Comment: Do your formulas do something like `=IF(foo, bar, "")`? What does "formulated blank" mean?

Comment: Yes, what I say formulated blank, I mean a formula happens and the result is an intentional blank cell = ""
The real formula looks something more like this
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT($F2,"0000000"),'Nesting WIP'!A:J,2,FALSE),"")
and the output is sometimes "" and sometimes it's an actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub setRangToCsv()

    Dim Filename As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange

    Filename = "comacsvtest.csv"
        
    TransToCSV Filename, rngDB

End Sub
Sub TransToCSV(myfile As String, rng As Range)

    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strFile As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        k = 0
        Erase vR ' add  this  line
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To k)
                vR(k) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strtxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strtxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is certainly interesting and a different direction which is probably they way I should be thinking, but this code also produces an unintended result.
this code takes the last line of data I have entered and fills in the rest of the rows with the last rows data, making several duplicate lines of data in the CSV file.

Comment: @Ace,  i edited answer.  `Erase vR` added.

Comment: Thank you, this code fixes my issue, although I'm still a bit confused why, it's clear you understand this more than I do, thank you thank you thank you.

now I just have to figure out how to clear the contents of the original .xslm update the naming number and place the user back at the start of the data to start the process over again.

Comment: thank you again, this code works and faster than mine and fixes my issue, I was able to add those functions in my previous comment and the code is working beautifully!   - I really wish I knew why.